# Centering uneven rows within a centered table

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to center a table and its rows in CSS.

I can center the table fine using:

```
table.Center
{
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

But when I try and call something similar on the table row I end up with the result below:

[image: http://i45.tinypic.com/259va.jpg]

The desired result being:

```
 XX
XXXX
XXXX
```

Used two instead of three for the sake of the visual.

How can I center the table row to the page?

Comment: You can't centre them for `n - 1` columned row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS solution:

```
table {
    text-align:center
}
td {
    display:inline-block
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gz3X2/

Comment: Good solution. I delete my jQuery based one.